# Sort the Qweb report line numerically in POS_Sale_detail report

Tags: reporting, odoo-11

I want to sort the qweb report from descending to ascending based on the below marked field,on the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9dTF.png)

the xml code for the report is as follows, the table must be sorted based on the field which is written in bold

#### Products

```
        <table class="table table-condensed">

            <thead><tr>

                <th>Product</th>

                <th>Quantity</th>

                <th>Cost Price</th>

                <th>Total Cost </th>

                <th>Price Unit</th>

                <th>Amount without VAT</th>

                <th>VAT</th>

                <th>VAT Amount</th>

                <th>Total Amount</th>

            </tr></thead>

            <tbody>

               <tr t-foreach="products" t-as="line">

                   <td>

                       <t t-esc="line['product_name']"/>
```

```
                       <td>

                       <t t-esc="line['quantity']"/>

                       <t t-if="line[&quot;uom&quot;] != &quot;Unit(s)&quot;">

                       <t t-esc="line[&quot;uom&quot;]"/> 

                       </t>

                       </td>

                       <td>

                       <t t-esc="'%.2f'%(request.env['product.product'].browse(line['product_id']).standard_price)"/>

                       </td>

                       <td>

                       <t t-esc="'%.2f'%(line['quantity']*request.env['product.product'].browse(line['product_id']).standard_price)"/>

                       </td>                  

                       <td>

                       <t t-esc="'%.2f'%line[&quot;price_unit&quot;]"/>

                       <t t-if="line[&quot;discount&quot;] != 0">

                       Disc: <t t-esc="line[&quot;discount&quot;]"/>%

                       </t>

                       </td>

                       <td>

                       <t t-esc="'%.2f'%((line['quantity']*line['price_unit'])/1.05)"/>

                       </td>

                       <td>

                       5%

                       </td>

                       <td>

                       <t t-esc="'%.2f'%(((line['quantity']*line['price_unit'])/1.05)*0.05)"/>

                       </td>

                       ****<td>
                       <t t-esc="'%.2f'%(line['quantity']*line['price_unit'])"/>
                       </td>****

            </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>
```

kindly give the code for the same field, and where to place the code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `products` is a list of dicts and you need to sort using `Total` *(quantity* * *price_unit)*.

You can use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with `t-foreach`:

```
<tr t-foreach="sorted(products, key=lambda d: d['quantity']*d['price_unit'])" t-as="line">
```

If you want to reverse the order, set `reverse` argument to `True`.